# Setting UITableView ContentInset

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am changing content insets bottom value manually.

```
literatureTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0);
```

This works fine but i want to set the value depending on the height of the table contents. I tried some things with tableView.bounds.size.height etc. but nothing is working.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to know the calculated bottom inset prior to displaying the reloaded data, then you must calculate the heights manually.

However, if your app permits you to call reloadData and then adjust the inset, you can arrive at it much more simply by doing this:

```
CGFloat trueContentHeight;

CGFloat heightWithInsets = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
UIEdgeInsets insets = self.tableView.contentInset;

trueContentHeight = heightWithInsets - (insets.top + insets.bottom);
```

Then you can calculate the bottom inset with the trueContentHeight and the height of the tableView's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

youll need to add up the height of your cells and headers (if you have any). You can use 
`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` from `self` to get the height's manually and add them up if they are not all the same.